# Xamarin Navigation PushAsync is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have this code

```
public App()
    {
       ... 

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
        App.Navigation.PushAsync(new homePage());
    }
```

the PushAsync does not work, it said the navigation is not defined, so can I prove to the compiler that Navigation is defined

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like the compiler is right. Your `App` won't have a `Navigation` property. What you probably need is:

```
MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new homePage());
```

Comment: Thank you, after changing it to PushModalAsync, I got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new homePage());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got my App() setup like this:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetail());
}
```

My MasterDetail looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="GrowersClassified.Views.Menu.MasterDetail"
         xmlns:detail="clr-namespace:GrowersClassified"
         xmlns:master="clr-namespace:GrowersClassified.Views.Menu"
         Title="">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <master:MasterPage x:Name="masterpage"/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <detail:Index/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

I think your problem might be using `App.`Navigation.PushAsync(new homePage());
For me it gave an error whenever I tried to use that anyways.